# Sencha Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release

Tags: jvm, nashorn

Any idea how to fix/remove this warning?

I am just doing a
`sencha app build` or
`npm run clean && cross-env webpack --env.profile=modern --env.environment=production --env.treeshake=yes`

OS is Ubuntu 18 LTS.

```sh
i [ext]: ext-webpack-plugin v7.2.0, Ext JS v7.2.0 Commercial Edition, Sencha Cmd v7.2.0.84, webpack v4.44.1n/a
i [ext]: Starting production build for extjs
i [ext]: Processing Build Descriptor : modern (production environment)
i [ext]:  [ERR] WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory (file:/builds/interpid/extjs-package-ipdu/node_modules/@sencha/cmd/dist/lib/closure-compiler-v20180610.jar) to field java.io.File.path WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] 
i [ext]: Loading compiler context
i [ext]: Loading app json manifest...
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]: Processing data with ClosureCompressor
i [ext]: Writing concatenated output to file /build/production/myApp/generatedFiles/modern/app.js
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]: Writing content to /build/temp/production/myApp/modern/slicer-temp/bootstrap.json
i [ext]: Writing content to /build/temp/production/myApp/modern/slicer-temp/bootstrap.js
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]: Writing content to /build/production/myApp/generatedFiles/modern.json
i [ext]: Fashion build complete for /build/temp/production/myApp/modern/sass/myApp-all.scss
i [ext]: Fashion build completed in 5.557 sec.
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]: Writing content to /build/production/myApp/generatedFiles/modern.json
i [ext]: Writing content to /build/production/myApp/microloader.js
i [ext]: Appending content to /build/production/myApp/microloader.js
i [ext]: Writing content to /build/production/myApp/index.html
i [ext]:  [ERR] Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
i [ext]: Ending production build for extjs
```

Comment: I've been wondering about this as well... I actually hope Sencha rewrites Cmd to not require Java, but for the moment, I guess we have to deal with that error output.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to follow up with this, as I had an epiphany the other day.  For my home projects, I realized that I didn't have to install Java when I started using the open tooling/npm approach.  At work, we have a project that was created before the open tooling approach, so we had to download and install the Sencha Cmd exe, which required Java.

Long story short, I uninstalled Java from my work machine, removed the `node_modules` dir and `package-lock.json` file, and re-ran npm install.  When I did this, I got a completely new `package-lock.json`, and the app built/ran without Java.  I think there are some smarts somewhere in the pipe to check to see if you have Java installed, and if you do, you get totally different dependencies.